# auto generate data - Syntax Error multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, syntax

```py
import random 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv

TOTAL_ROWS = 10 

USERNAMES = ['John', 'Jack', 'Bob']
LOG_TYPE = ['CLAIMED_DEAL', 'SELECTED_DEAL', 'SELECTED_BUSINESS']

# deal: NAME, PRICE, DISCOUNTED_PRICE
DEALS = [ ['SALAD', 80, 40], ['Burger', 180, 120], ['Pho', 50, 40] ]


def random_date(start, end):
    """Generate a random datetime between `start` and `end`"""
    return start + timedelta(
        # Get a random amount of seconds between `start` and `end`
        seconds=random.randint(0, int((end - start).total_seconds())),
    )


NOW = datetime.now()

if __name__== "__main__":

    with open('data.csv', "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

        # header 
        writer.writerow([ 'timestamp','username','type', 'deal_title', 'deal_price', 'deal_discounted_price' ])
        for i in range(TOTAL_ROWS):
            deal = random.choice(DEALS)

            writer.writerow([
                random_date(start=(NOW - timedelta(days=7)), end=NOW).timestamp(), # timestamp
                random.choice(USERNAMES), # username
                random.choice(LOG_TYPE), # type
                deal[0], # title
                deal[1], # price 
                deal[2], # discouned price

            ])
```

Comment: That code works well for me

Comment: works for me as well. What is the exact stacktrace you're getting?